# new-pssession previously working code now gets Access is denied

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I hope someone can shed some light on this one, I've been using the below code below to create a new PSSession for months and has been working perfectly! Until today where it has suddenly started giving the error:

```
New-PSSession : [IPAddressHere] Connecting to remote server IPAddressHere failed with the following error message :
Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:5 char:15
+    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName IPAddressHere -Credential $cred
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError:     (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

Code that errors:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "*" -Force
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "MyPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential  ("Domain\MyUsername", $password )
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName IPAddressHere -Credential $cred
```

Code that works with identical copy/pasted username/password from origonal code

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "*" -Force
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName IPAddressHere -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

But the code that now errors has been working for so long, no updates have been ran and no AD changes other than I changed my password last week. But this also happens to all existing AD accounts and even for a new administrator account. I can RDP into the server fine, Also tried restarting with no effect.

I'm on a separate domain from the server's that I execute the code on.

Any ideas as at the minute I've tried adding get credentials to my app but as powershell is called from within a Windows Forms .NET application the Get-Credentials popup doesn't appear to allow the workaround of asking for credentials each time.

Regards

Liam

Comment: I had a problem like this a couple months ago due to stored credentials on my local machine.  In Control Panel, check Credential Manager and see if you have any stored credentials that might be interfering.  After checking that, I'd run IPCONFIG /flushdns in an elevated console on your local machine to blow anything lingering out.  Try again after that.

Comment: I've tried from different machine on the same network and get the error when specifying credentials but if I don't specify then it works fine (using server name instead of IP, otherwise it won't auto use current credentials). So it definitely isn't credential manager or permissions to the remote session as it works with either popup credentials or built in when on the same domain. Frustrating that it's happened so randomly... It's the same with all 4 webservers that I connect to like this. Thank you for your suggestions by the way :-)